# User country selection and SEO concerns

Tags: asp.net, seo, modal-dialog

I want my users when visiting the website to select which country they are from, it will then store this in a cookie and won't bother them again. A number of different parts of the system (such as system pricing) rely on this so it can be converted to a users currency.

I'm thinking of displaying a modal on any page when the country cookie not set, however I'm worried about negatively impacting my site when it comes to SEO.

Has anyone had experience of this? I want Google to crawl all entries for all countries, but if a user is actually visiting the site there is no point in displaying entries for a different country (the website allows visitors to search for a type of instructor within their local area).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a cleaner approach, but...  Make your pages that rely on a country cookie also accept a query string parameter that specifies which country to use (you can use URL rewriting to make this more SEO friendly http://example.com/learning/12233/usa/, http://example.com/learning/12246/germany/).  Then make a page which lists all of these items by country.  On your country selection page you can put a link underneath the drop down box that says "or browse all countries".  Now google should be able to find all the information for all countries.